# modify macro to make it run faster

Tags: excel, csv, optimization, vba

Who can help with this macro?
It's merging csv files into one.
csv files can be more than 500 and its running slow.
By the way it's taiking all data in csv file (2 rows). it will work for me if macro can take just second row from file..

Any ideas?

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportCSV65()

Dim strSourcePath As String
Dim strDestPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strData As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Change the path to the source folder accordingly
strSourcePath = Worksheets("Tarpinis").Range("AJ8").Value

If Right(strSourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then strSourcePath = strSourcePath & "\"

strFile = Dir(strSourcePath & "*.csv")
Sheets("+65").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    Cnt = Cnt + 1
    If Cnt = 1 Then
        r = 1
    Else
        r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
    Open strSourcePath & strFile For Input As #1
        If Cnt > 1 Then
            Line Input #1, strData
        End If
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, strData
            x = Split(strData, ",")
            For c = 0 To UBound(x)
                Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(x(c))
            Next c
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
    Name strSourcePath & strFile As strSourcePath & strFile
    strFile = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If Cnt = 0 Then _
 MsgBox "No CSV files were found...", vbExclamation

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: if it's working then it may be more suitable on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ anyway VBA is not a good tool for this, due to the lack of multithreading and bad compiler optimization. If you're merging vertically then simply concatenating the files would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following, it will read the second line from each CSV file in the given folder and write that line in the Sheet +65:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportCSV65()
Dim strSourcePath As String
Dim strDestPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strData As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim counter As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("+65")

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
counter = 0
'Change the path to the source folder accordingly
strSourcePath = Worksheets("Tarpinis").Range("AJ8").Value

If Right(strSourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then strSourcePath = strSourcePath & "\"

strFile = Dir(strSourcePath & "*.csv")

Do While Len(strFile) > 0

    Open strSourcePath & strFile For Input As #1

        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, strData
            r = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            counter = counter + 1
                If counter = 2 Then 'counter to get only second line
                x = Split(strData, ",")
                    For c = 0 To UBound(x)
                        ws.Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(x(c))
                    Next c
                    r = r + 1
                    Exit Do
                End If
        Loop
    Close #1
    Name strSourcePath & strFile As strSourcePath & strFile
    strFile = Dir
    counter = 0 'reset counter before next file
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, i try your code i think it works more faster!

Comment: @Xabier, if you only want row 2, why not drop out of the loop once row 2 is read?

Comment: @CLR thanks for the pointer, I don't even know how I missed that, updated my answer..

Answer (score 1):

The only obvious place that I can see that could be done better is the loop that writes the trimmed values into the cells.

If you must trim each value, then you'll still need to loop through the array and `Trim` it:

```
For c = 0 To UBound(x)
    x(c) = Trim(x(c))
Next c
```

But to write to the cells, you can speed things up by writing the array directly to the range:

```
Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, UBound(x) + 1).Value = x
```

You might also gain a little bit of time by qualifying the destination sheet, preferably as a `With`.

So the whole thing would look like this:

```
Sub ImportCSV65()

Dim strSourcePath As String
Dim strDestPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strData As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Change the path to the source folder accordingly
strSourcePath = Worksheets("Tarpinis").Range("AJ8").Value

If Right(strSourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then strSourcePath = strSourcePath & "\"

strFile = Dir(strSourcePath & "*.csv")

With Sheets("+65")
    .Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        Cnt = Cnt + 1
        If Cnt = 1 Then
            r = 1
        Else
            r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If
        Open strSourcePath & strFile For Input As #1
            If Cnt > 1 Then
                Line Input #1, strData
            End If
            Do Until EOF(1)
                Line Input #1, strData
                x = Split(strData, ",")
                For c = 0 To UBound(x)
                    x(c) = Trim(x(c))
                Next c
                .Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, UBound(x) + 1).Value = x
                r = r + 1
            Loop
        Close #1
        Name strSourcePath & strFile As strSourcePath & strFile
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If Cnt = 0 Then _
 MsgBox "No CSV files were found...", vbExclamation

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Workbooks.Open Filename:=strSourcePath & strFile, Format:=2
This code will open csv file as excel type.
And get data as variant vlaue and will fill your sheet by variant value.

```
Sub ImportCSV65()

    Dim strSourcePath As String
    Dim strDestPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strData As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, rngT As Range

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Change the path to the source folder accordingly
    strSourcePath = Worksheets("Tarpinis").Range("AJ8").Value

    If Right(strSourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then strSourcePath = strSourcePath & "\"

    strFile = Dir(strSourcePath & "*.csv")
    Set Ws = Sheets("+65")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Ws
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=strSourcePath & strFile, Format:=2
            With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
                vDB = .UsedRange
            End With
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Set rngT = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
            rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
            strFile = Dir
        Loop
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```